# How to write capital beta in Latex like in the beta distribution

Tags: amsmath, greek, letters

What is the code for the capital beta sign in picture below?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It is is not a capital beta  (which is the same as our B in greek), but  a calligraphic B (command: `\mathcal{B}`).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying sir!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `y \sim \mathcal{B}(\mu,\phi)`. That means that 'B' is not an uppercase beta but a calligraphic B.
[image]
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is a very useful tool to find out how special characters can be achieved. Please note that you need to load `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 4):

Traditional TeX has no `$\Beta$`, and just uses `$B$`. You’ve already gotten an answer saying that symbol is `\mathcal{B}`.

However, `unicode-math`, for LuaTeX or XeTeX, does have a `$\Beta$` distinct from `$B$`, but in most fonts, they look identical. (, U+1D6E3  versus , U+1D435.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
\( y \sim \symit{\Beta}(\mu, \psi) \).
Compare \(B\).
\end{document}
```

[image]